# how to Format an equation to update progressbar

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

Im trying to wrap my head around this but am spending too much time on it and cant find answers else where. 
I have a progress bar that I need to update. I created a timer to hit a method every .1 seconds until the Data has downloaded. Then I will invalidate the timer. 
My question is.. how would I format an equation to update the progress bar. I already know what the total file size will be and it is in bytes. I believe the answer will be close to something like this but I just cant get it to work.

```
int f = fileSize;  // I already know what filesize is going to be. for demo purposes lets say 19000000 bytes

float d = (z/10000000);

progressInt = (d * f);
progBar.progress = progressInt;
```

I think it something along those lines?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress is usually represented as a float between 0 and 1.  `bytesLoaded/filesize` will be 0 when no bytes are loaded and 1 when it is fully loaded.